# Is it possible to reduce the Input Ouput of a select request SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with more then 30M records. this is a production table. I want to run a select * where ..... but i have trouble with I/O usage limitation. I need to keep the restriction on I/O up to keep the Database running smootly. Is it possible to limit the disk usage of a request. It's Oracle.

I would like to have something along the lines of:
Select * from table where... limit disk usage to x

Comment: You need to report the actual database engine you are using.

Comment: Oracle....10g or later by any chance?  Database resource manager my assist you here. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/dbrm.htm#i1010776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile can be used to limit the amount of I/O used by a specific SQL statement.

From the [`CREATE PROFILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310) chapter of the SQL Language Reference:

> LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL
>
> Specify the permitted number of data blocks read for a call to process a SQL statement (a parse, execute, or fetch).

For creating a quick test, let's set an unreasonably low size limit of 100MB.  Assuming the standard block size of 8KB, the limit should be 100*1024*1024 / (8*1024) = 12800 blocks.

```
create profile reduced_io limit logical_reads_per_call 12800;
```

Now create a few simple tables and select all the data in them, to see exactly when the statements fail.  Without any indexes, running a `select count(*)` on these tables should read every byte in the segment.

```
drop table test_40m;
drop table test_60m;
drop table test_80m;
drop table test_120m;

create table test_40m(a varchar2(1000));
create table test_60m(a varchar2(1000));
create table test_80m(a varchar2(1000));
create table test_120m(a varchar2(1000));

insert into test_40m select lpad('a', 1000, 'a') from dual connect by level <= 30 * 1024;
insert into test_60m select lpad('a', 1000, 'a') from dual connect by level <= 50 * 1024;
insert into test_80m select lpad('a', 1000, 'a') from dual connect by level <= 70 * 1024;
insert into test_120m select lpad('a', 1000, 'a') from dual connect by level <= 100 * 1024;
commit;
```

The numbers above probably look weird.  For example, it inserts 50MB of data into the 60MB table.  This is because with things like segment/block/row overhead and automatic extent sizing, it's hard to get the segment sizes just right.  But they're close enough for a quick test.

```
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 mb from dba_segments where segment_name like 'TEST_%M';

SEGMENT_NAME   MB
------------   --
TEST_40M       35
TEST_60M       59
TEST_80M       88
TEST_120M      120
```

Now create a user with that profile and the ability to SELECT from those tables:

```
drop user test_user;
create user test_user identified by "test_user#1A" profile reduced_io;
grant create session to test_user;
grant select on test_60m to test_user;
grant select on test_80m to test_user;
grant select on test_120m to test_user;
```

Login with that user and try to query all the data in the tables.  Small queries succeed and larger queries fail:

```
sqlplus test_user/test_user#1A

...

SQL> select count(*) from jheller.test_40m;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     30720

SQL> select count(*) from jheller.test_60m;
select count(*) from jheller.test_60m
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage


SQL>
```

The limit throws an exception, but too soon.  It shouldn't fail on a 60 megabyte table when the limit is 100 megabytes.  A lot of the profile features are not exact and it's hard to measure exactly how much I/O Oracle is reading and writing.

(Officially the resource manager is supposed to allow more control over these kinds of things.  But I've never seen it used in practice.  In the real-world not many people have the time or knowledge to precisely define exactly how many resources should be allocated to who.)

You should test this thoroughly in your environment before implementing it.  It will probably never be highly accurate but it may be good enough to stop some ridiculous queries.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create store procedure and then ren if need to executed the select query they will help you with  no reduce input output error

USE [Databasename]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create procedure [dbo].[TableName]
as
begin
select * from Table where 
end

Comment: Don't think you understand what the question is asking here.